# Xcode Image cropping produces output which has pixel imperfections

Tags: ios, xcode, image, crop

Im using the following code to crop my UIImage:

```
-(UIImage*)cropWithRect:(CGRect)rect
{
   if(self.scale > 1.0f){
       rect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x * self.scale,
                      rect.origin.y * self.scale,
                      rect.size.width * self.scale,
                      rect.size.height * self.scale);
   }

   CGImageRef imageRef = (CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(self.CGImage, rect));
   return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:self.scale orientation:self.imageOrientation];
}
```

But this gives me an output image which has wrong pixel colors which is noticeable when zoomed in. For instance, white input pixel sometimes becomes off-white (not always - only when the white pixels are close to other pixels of dark colors).

Can I get better results or is there another way to produce better cropped images?

Thanks.

Comment: provide the code where you initialize graphic context

Comment: You don't need graphics context for this API. The code I posted is literally all the code that does cropping.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you [FXImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXImageView)
Step 1: select Image
[image: step 1]
Step 2: Crop Image
[image: step 2]
Step 3: Result Image
[image: result Image]

Comment: No go. The crop code used in that library produces even worse results than mine.

Comment: I don't think so. Take these images, zoom in to pixel level and then compare. Besides this image is very colorful therefore very hard to notice the difference. Just take images of Japanese flag, then use this to crop out something, you would notice smears of off-white pixels in the cropped image specially around the red circle.